# Find Membership query

Tags: civimember

I created 2 smart groups for mailings.  One to pull all "current" members, one to pull all lapsed members.

In my lapsed group I set membership status = expired or cancelled, and current membership = no.
However, I am getting current/active members showing up in my lapsed group and I don't understand what I did wrong?

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Are any of those people folk who had a Membership (so yes Expired is True) but also have a second Membership that is Current?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that current member = no is finding contacts with a non-current membership (but who might also have a current membership as well), rather than contacts who don't have a current membership at all. Can you verify if that's the case? Do these contacts have two memberships, one expired and one current? We could add a help text to Current member in Advanced Search indicating this is what's actually happening in the background or even look at improving this. I have found that current member gives unexpected results in the past as well.

If you use SearchKit instead, searching for:

- Contacts
- with (required) a Contact Membership with status one of expired or cancelled
- without a Contact Membership with status one of new, pending, current (or using whichever statuses are appropriate)

you should get the results you're looking for.

Comment: I confirmed on master that Current Member does as I suggested above, which is not great. I added an issue here:
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3943

Comment: @erin if you're able to weigh on the Gitlab issue, I think that might help push this forward.

Comment: Yes exactly, and as petednz said above these people have an expired membership but also a current/active membership.  So they were added to both of my smart groups! (not good because they got 2 emails, one saying they were a current member and one saying they were a lapsed member - caused lots of confusion....lol

Answer (score 1):

Finding Members who have a Current Membership and do not also have an Expired Membership, or vice versa, can be done using SearchKit by using a Without' join. (was mentioned here https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/hnbkc3f8u7r69q1u1zbf6caozr)